# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election)!

Answer (score 2):

Reemrevnivek ran the results. Thought I would post it for easy reference.

```
Loading ballots from file election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 8 candidates and 55 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 55 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Electronics Design Moderator Election 2011 using Meek STV.
8 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|Kortuk         |Kellenjb       |reemrevnivek   |markrages      |Nick T         |Madmanguruman  
  |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------
  |Dean           |Daniel Grillo  |Exhausted      |Surplus        |Threshold      
==================================================================================================
 1|      24.000000|       1.000000|      11.000000|      14.000000|       2.000000|       2.000000
  |       0.000000|       1.000000|       0.000000|      10.499998|      13.750001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidates Kortuk and markrages have reached the threshold and are
  | elected.
==================================================================================================
 2|      13.842083|       1.869418|      15.359926|      16.266741|       3.314358|       2.017857
  |       0.434709|       1.040735|       0.854173|       4.859379|      13.536457
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Kortuk, 0.572917 and markrages, 0.982143. Candidate reemrevnivek has reached the
  | threshold and is elected.

Winners are Kortuk, reemrevnivek, and markrages.
```